# Android using onActivityResult inside Fragment

Tags: android

I want to simply use `zxing` barcode scanner into project, for this action I'm using [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-create-a-barcode-reader--mobile-17162) to implemented barcode reader into project, this tutorial use two `Zxing` class into project, in my application I don't have Activity and I'm using `Fragment`,unfortunately I could not get data from `onActivityResult` to get scanContent of barcode:

```
public class FragmentAddNewWayBill extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        G.currentActivity = FragmentAddNewWayBill.this.getActivity();
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_new_waybill, container, false);

        view.findViewById(R.id.imgv_scan_barcode).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(G.currentActivity);
                scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (scanningResult != null) {
            String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
            String scanFormat = scanningResult.getFormatName();
            Log.e("barcode is: ", scanContent);
            Toast.makeText(G.currentActivity,scanContent, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else{
            Log.e("No scan data received! ", "");
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(G.currentActivity,"No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Implementation will be depend upon, how startactivityforresult is called.
Hope startactivityforresult is called from the library and its calling as it is calling from activity.
So the requestCode, resultCode will be proper in activity onActivityResult.
So, move the code of onActivityResult to Activty, everything works.

If getActivity().startactivityforresult is called then it is calling from Fragment. then onActivityResult should be working fine.

Comment: thanks sir, unfortunatelly i could not use  `getActivity().startActivity();` whats parameter of this function sir? i dont have any intent in fragment to start that

Comment: Just move onActivityResult code to activity class, everything works

Answer (score 0):

I also had problems w/ the ZXing  Barcode reader
if u need to scan QR Codes i would recoment the Qr-Droid API its very simple and u can start it without problems from a Fragment

```
    public class SrnSuche extends Fragment {
        Context context;
    @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {

           final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_srnsuche, container, false);

            Button Button_such = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_suchen);
            Button Button_scan = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_scan);
            context = rootView.getContext();

            Button_scan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {




                    Intent qrDroid = new Intent( "la.droid.qr.scan" );
                    qrDroid.putExtra( "la.droid.qr.complete" , true);
                    try {
                    startActivityForResult(qrDroid, 0);
                        //ja=true;
                    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException activity) {
                      //  ja=false;
                        qrDroidRequired(getActivity());
                    }
                }
            });
    }
            return rootView;
       public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
//retrieve scan result
        /*
        IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (scanningResult != null) {
            String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,
                "SCAN THERE "+scanContent, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            Intent i = new Intent(context, Historie_Activity.class);
            i.putExtra("value_seriennummer", scanContent);
            startActivity(i);
            toast.show();


        }else{
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,
                    "No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }*/

if (intent!= null){
        String result = intent.getExtras().getString("la.droid.qr.result");
        if (result != null) {

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,
                    "SCAN THERE "+result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            Intent i = new Intent(context, Historie_Activity.class);
            i.putExtra("value_seriennummer", result);
            startActivity(i);
            toast.show();


        }else{
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,
                    "No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
}
    }
 }
```

link to QR-Droid API [click](http://qrdroid.com/android-developers/#2)

Answer (score 0):

I just got the same problem using zxing library.
So you have to create a broadcast receiver in your fragment and register it. So inside the onActivityResult in your activity, you send a broadcast with the scanContent and scanformat. You will receive those value inside your broadcast receiver you have created in the fragment.